# Swing JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated vs UIManager.setLookAndFeel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, theming

In Swing, it appears there are two ways of setting the theme/look-and-feel of the application:

- `JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated`, and
- `UIManager.setLookAndFeel`

I'm wondering what the difference is between these is and when/why to use either of them.

Comment: this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139088/jframe-setdefaultlookandfeeldecoratedtrue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(...)` methods allow setting the look and feel of the application. This is the method you want to use to set a specific look and feel to your application.

Using the static `JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(...)` will only affect how newly created `JFrame`s will have their windows "decorated" (i.e. window title bar, close/minimize button etc). Either by the `LookAndFeel` or by the system (or the "window manager"). It does not affect the look and feel of the application in general.

From the docs:

> If `defaultLookAndFeelDecorated` is `true`, the current `LookAndFeel` supports providing window decorations, and the current window manager supports undecorated windows, then newly created `JFrames` will have their Window decorations provided by the current `LookAndFeel`. Otherwise, newly created `JFrames` will have their Window decorations provided by the current window manager.

Personally, I rarely find good use for the latter method.